# Can we instantiate an abstract class directly?

Tags: java, android, class, oop, abstract

I have read we can only instantiate an abstract class by inheriting it, but we cannot instantiate it directly.
However, I saw we can create an object with the type of an abstract class by calling a method of another class.
For example - `LocationProvider` is an abstract class, and we can instantiate it by calling `getProvider()` function in the `LocationManager` class:

```
LocationManager lm = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_PROVIDER);
LocationProvider lp = lm.getProvider("gps");
```

How is the abstract class instantiate here?

Comment: Among other things, Chuck Norris can instanciate abstract classes: http://www.ithoughts.de/chuck-norris-programmer-facts ;-)

Comment: Chuck Norris can do a lot of other tricks in programming: http://chucknorrisfacts.co.uk/fact/category/4/

Comment: LocationProvider is not an abstract class i think , its just a normal public class as you can see here. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationProvider.html You might be telling this cause they used abstract word in the class documentation.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can't directly instantiate an abstract class, but you can create an anonymous class when there is no concrete class:

```
public class AbstractTest {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final Printer p = new Printer() {
            void printSomethingOther() {
                System.out.println("other");
            }
            @Override
            public void print() {
                super.print();
                System.out.println("world");
                printSomethingOther(); // works fine
            }
        };
        p.print();
        //p.printSomethingOther(); // does not work
    }
}

abstract class Printer {
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

This works with interfaces, too.

Comment: can we have function definition inside abstract class?

Comment: You can create methods inside anonymous classes, but you can only call these methods inside of the anonymous class. See the code in my answer, I edited it.

Comment: @sschaef, can you explain why the call to `p.printSomethingOther` works fine from inside the class but not from outside?

Comment: @Cupidvogel: because it is not public/not known to type `Printer`.

Comment: What word would you describe this as, if not "instantiation"?

Comment: @JamesWierzba it is instantiation, just not of the abstract class but the anonymous subclass.

Comment: @sschaef  Is it allowed for an `abstract` class (in this case `Printer`) to have only concrete method(s) [method(s) with definition]? Any class must have at least one `abstract` method to become `abstract` right?

Comment: @AnV For a class to be abstract, you just need to define it `abstract`. It can then have 0 abstract methods along with any number of concrete methods.

(see: [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811678/defining-an-abstract-class-without-any-abstract-methods))

Answer (score 23):

No, you can never instantiate an abstract class. That's the purpose of an abstract class. The `getProvider` method you are referring to returns a specific implementation of the abstract class. This is the abstract factory pattern.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on factory pattern or give some link about that?

Comment: @satheesh.droid, here's an example: http://www.javabeat.net/tips/18-factory-pattern-design-patterns-in-javaj.html

Comment: What's the motivation for placing the `create[Object]` method in a separate `[Object]Factory` class rather than in the abstract `[Object]` class itself? To use the example in your link: What's the motivation for placing the `createButton` method in a separate `ButtonFactory` class rather than in the abstract `Buttton` class itself?

Answer (score 5):

No, abstract class can never be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

According to others said, you cannot instantiate from abstract class. but it exist 2 way to use it. 
1. make another non-abstact class that extends from abstract class. So you can instantiate from new class and use the attributes and methods in abstract class.

```
    public class MyCustomClass extends YourAbstractClass {

/// attributes, methods ,...
}
```

2. work with interfaces.