# Can we create public static abstract class in java?

Tags: java

I was searching in google for something and I got a code like

```
public static abstract class LocationResult{
    public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
}
```

It's a nested class but wondering how it could be accessible ?

Comment: You can check it out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579305/can-we-instantiate-abstract-class

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It must be a nested class: the static keyword on the *class* (not methods within it) is only used (and syntactically valid) for nested classes. Such **static member classes** (to use Java in a Nutshell's common nomenculture) hold no reference to the enclosing class, and thus can only access static fields and methods within it (unlike non-static ones; see any summary of nested classes in Java (also known as inner classes).

It can be accessible like this:

```
public class EnclosingClass {
  public static abstract class LocationResult{
    public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
  }
}

EnclosingClass.LocationResult locationResult = ...
```

Comment: Or it could be extended by other nested classes.

Comment: as a newbie i learn we can not create an instance of a abstract class.is there any documentation of material to learn this?

Comment: @YasirKhan You can in the form of an anonymous class.

Comment: @Yasir - like any other abstract class, you need to inherit and create a concrete subclass whom you can instantiate. A variable can be of the type of the superclass, and hold a reference to the subclass - this is called upcasting.

Comment: @DavidRabinowitz why we are using static keyword here?

Comment: @YasirKhan I edited the answer to better explain why the static keyword is there.

Answer (score 4):

Only nested classes can be static. By doing so you can use the nested class without having an instance of the outer class.

So you could create a class extending it using `extends Mainclass.LocationResult` and use it with `Mainclass.LocationResult instance = ...`