# Cannot instantiate an abstract class

Tags: java, oop, instantiation

```
package InterfaceAbstractOverloadingOverriding;

public class instrumentExecute 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
         GuitarAbstract g = new GuitarAbstract();
         NewGuitar ng = new NewGuitar(); 
         g.play();
         ng.play();

         g = new GuitarAbstract(7);
         ng = new NewGuitar(5);
         g.play();
         ng.play();
    }
}
```

I'm not able to instantiate the `GuitarAbstract` class

Error:

```
Cannot instantiate the type GuitarAbstract.GuitarAbstract is an abstract class.
```

Comment: You can't directly instantiate an abstract class : [http://stackoverflow.com/q/4579305/4682796](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4579305/4682796)

Comment: That's because it's an abstract class.  You need to create something concrete that inherits from that class in order to be able to instantiate something.

Comment: Please, follow java naming conventions. Packages are to be all lowercase, classes on the other hand should be camel-case (InstrumentExecute) for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly instantiate an abstract class, but you can instantiate an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) for your abstract class.

For example, given the following abstract class:

```
class GuitarAbstract {

  public abstract void play();
}
```

You can create an anonymous class like so:

```
GuitarAbstract guitar = new GuitarAbstract() {

  @Override
  public void play() {
    System.out.println("Playing guitar!");
  }
};
```