# How to instantiate an abstract class in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, abstract-class

I came up with the following problem:

My MainActivity code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // ...
        // ERROR: Cannot create instance of an abstract class
        var db = DataBase().getDataBase(this)
        // ...
    }
}
```

Room's Database:

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(DataBaseUser::class), version = 1)
abstract class DataBase : RoomDatabase() {

    val DB_NAME : String = "DataBaseUser"
    private lateinit var INSTANCE : DataBase

    fun getDataBase(context: Context): DataBase {
        if (INSTANCE == null){
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,DataBase::class.java,DB_NAME).build()
        }
        return INSTANCE
    }

    abstract fun getUserDao(): DataBaseUserDao
}
```

I can not instantiate the class in Kotlin. In Java I did it like this:

```
db = AppDataBase.getDataBase(view.getContext());
```

How can I get the same result in Kotlin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we instantiate an abstract class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579305/can-we-instantiate-an-abstract-class)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a singleton (in Kotlin `object`) to hold the Room database instance:

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(DataBaseUser::class), version = 1)
abstract class DataBase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getUserDao(): DataBaseUserDao
}

object DatabaseProvider {
  private const val DB_NAME: String = "DataBaseUser"
  private lateinit var dbInstance: DataBase

  fun getDatabase(context: Context): DataBase {

    if (!this::dbInstance.isInitialized) {
      dbInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(
        context.applicationContext,
        DataBase::class.java,
        DB_NAME
      ).build()
    }

    return dbInstance
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
val db = DatabaseProvider.getDatabase(view.getContext())
```

Answer (score 3):

For instantiate abstract class in Kotlin you use `object: <your class>`.
Example:

```
abstract class AbstractTest {
    abstract fun someFun(): Int
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val astractInstance = object : AbstractTest() {
        override fun someFun(): Int {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below

```
var db = object: DataBase(){
    override fun getUserDao(): DataBase{
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```